Acces rights, record rules and notification and messages V14
i have kind of problem understanding access rights and maybe an issue resolving this, i'v created acces right for my model "tg_quart" , and add a record rule to the same model so that the user can't edit when the state field is not equal to 'draft', but i want that the user can leave a message or note (in the chatter section) to other in case he found somthing not right in the data,  but that not possible in this case as long as the record rules is there and preventing it.
here the code :
ir.model.access.csv
access_exploitation_tg_quart_dr,exploitation.tg_quart,exploitation.model_tg_quart,exploitation.group_tg_data_prd_report,1,1,1,0

<record id="exploitation_rule_etats_draft" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Modifier seulment dans etats draft</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_tg_quart"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('state', '=','draft')]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref ('exploitation.group_tg_data_prd_report'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
</record>

Is there anyone who had this kind of issue and have a solution??
